# Update Multiple Postgres Tables with 1 query or function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have three different tables, and I am looking to update all three of them at the same time with Postgres. I'd like to use 1 single query (be it a transaction, or stored procedure/function) to update all of them.

I had thought about putting everything into a view, and create a rule to update the view, but I am not sure that is the most efficient way to do an update. I am pulling in all the information from the below "SELECT" query into a form on the front end. I would like to update any/all of the changed data. For example, if I update the entity, first name, and role I'd like to update all the corresponding tables.

Question: How can I update all three tables with 1 call to the database? If that is not possible, what is the most efficient way to update all three at the same time?

Currently, the query to pull in all data is as follows:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, r.role_name as role, u.username, e.entity 
FROM users u 
  INNER JOIN roles r  ON u.role_id = r.role_id 
  INNER JOIN entities e ON u.entity_Id = e.entity_Id 
WHERE u.user_id =1
```

Tables Referenced:

User

```
        Column        |           Type           |
----------------------+--------------------------+
 user_id              | integer                  |
 firstname            | character varying(50)    |
 lastname             | character varying(50)    |
 role_id              | integer                  |
 entity_id            | integer                  |

Foreign-key constraints:
    "entity_fk" FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES entities(entity_id)
    "role_fk" FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(role_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "entities" CONSTRAINT "entities_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
    TABLE "roles" CONSTRAINT "roles_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
```

Roles

```
  Column   |         Type          |
-----------+-----------------------+
 role_id   | integer               |
 role_name | character varying(50) |
 user_id   | integer               |

Foreign-key constraints:
    "roles_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "users" CONSTRAINT "role_fk" FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(role_id)
```

Entities

```
    Column     |         Type          |
---------------+-----------------------+
 entity_id     | integer               |
 entity        | character varying(50) |
 user_id       | integer               |

Foreign-key constraints:
    "entity_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "users" CONSTRAINT "entity_fk" FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES entities(entity_id)
```

Comment: What exactly is it you want to update?

Comment: If I have a form that has all of the user data, I'd like to be update anything that has changed. I will update the question with this information

Comment: Don't make things more complicated then needed. Send three `update` statements in a single transaction. No magic required

Comment: I know this is slightly off topic, but would the same be true if I wanted to add a new user- Create three insert statements within a single transaction?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's precisely what transactions are for.

Comment: Ok perfect. One final note- Can I embed a transaction within a stored procedure? From what I can tell, it doesn't look like Postgres supports that, nor does it have (from what I can tell) a difference between functions and stored procs. I'd hate to call the multi level transaction within the app layer.